# Determine how service was started

Tags: android, android-service

Haven't found a similar question, if one exists, please point me to it.

Basically I want to know how a running service was started. Mainly it interests me if the service has been started with StartService(), regardless of how many bindings it has.

So, I am looking for something like:

```
if(service has (also) been started with startService) {
   // do something
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the flags and intent that you're passed in `onStartCommand`. When you want to find out how you were started, refer back to those.